# APC and "apc.gc_ttl" :: How Low is Too Low?

Tags: php5, alternative-php-cache

I currently have my `apc.gc_ttl` set to `600` to help keep fragmentation down.

Since `apc.gc_ttl` just sets the time on cache for garbage collection, I don't see any harm in keeping it this low.

However, I'm new to APC, and have seen many configurations online that use a 3600 TTL, which seems quite long to me for garbage collection cache...

Is `600` too low? Is `3600` too high?

As I'm sure mileage varies on this setup, is there a good rule of thumb to follow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`600` is not low for `apc.gc_ttl` and `3600` is actually the default value, you are right that it will vary on different installations, I have mine set to 600 as well.